# Calculate the number of different elements in a subset( number of distinct ID's for every Item.)

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

I am currently working with some Excel data that looks like this:

```
ITEM_NAME   ITEM_ID
_________   _________
Item_1      ID1_Item1
Item_1      ID2_Item_1
Item_1      ID3_Item_1
Item_2      ID1_Item2
Item_2      ID2_Item_2
Item_2      ID3_Item_2
Item_2      ID4_Item_2
Item_3      ID1_Item3
Item_3      ID2_Item_3
```

I am trying to calculate the **number of distinct ID's for every Item**.

So from the above example I am trying to get the results:

```
Item_1      3
Item_2      4
Item_3      2
```

---

What I tried is marking distinct elements for 1 specific item, then summing them up.
However, this is inefficient and I always have to check

```
 IF [ITEM_NAME] = "Item_1" THEN 1 END
```

Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Extract your data (to a TDE file). Easy stuff, just go to your data connectio, right click then extract.

Second: Drag Item_name to rows and columns, and for the rows one, right click and go on measure -> Count (Distinct)

In case you want to know how to do it in formula, it's COUNTD(Item_name). It's an aggregate field.

You need to extract because countd is not supported for direct Excel connection.

EDIT: Apparently Tableau 8.2 support COUNTD even for Excel connections, so no need to extract (though it's often a good idea)